# Creating Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am having trouble creating an Azure Search instance from the preview portal:

[image: Error message from Azure Search]

> Search creation failed in resource group x.

I have tried different combinations of:

- resource groups (even created a new one)
- regions (East US, West Europe, North Europe)
- pricing tiers (both free and standard)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Vegard, I am looking into this for you.  Would you mind telling me the approximate date & time you tried this?  It is possible that this was some temporary issue with the Azure Portal.

Comment: @LiamCavanagh This must have been around 10:00 - 10:30 GMT today. And I just tried it again now. No luck.

Comment: This is really odd, I just tried to create a free service in West Europe and it succeeded.  Let me keep looking...

Comment: Vegard.  Just as an update, it looks like there is something odd about your Azure subscription.  We are still looking into the specifics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a transient Azure issue, and not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close on this issue, we have determined that there was an issue with the Azure portal in a recent update that is causing new subscriptions to fail to create new Azure Search services.  This would explain why it worked for me but failed for you (as I suspect you have a new subscription).

The Azure portal is working to roll back this change.  I am still waiting to get the time but I am hopeful this should happen in the next day or two.

I really apologize for this issue.

Liam

Comment: Liam, thanks for the quick response. I was indisposed last night so I didn't get a chance to reply. I tried again this morning, but still didn't work (but I guess the change hasn't been reverted yet). Our subscription started 6/11/2012, so it is not a particularly new subscription. Your comment with your e-mail disappeared, but feel free to e-mail me at vegard AT digitalcreations DOT no, and I can send you the subscription ID.

Comment: Thanks Vegard, I will post here the results of the findings for others to see in case this happens again.

Answer (score 0):

Its advisable to check the limits while planning to create azure search. here are some details:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-limits-quotas-capacity/

Comment: Alghough providing a link to specs is good, you should include the main parts to your answer (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)